# salesforce API account creation

Tags: salesforce

We've created C# classes for the WSDL file provided by Salesforce.

Most of the classes generated are entity classes, but it seems you don't have any methods to call such as CreateAccount or UpdateAccount.

Is that correct? Do you use a query to do all data manipulation directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having separate create methods for each of the object, Salesforce provides a generic method of create which accepts input of generic object which can be of type account or contact or any custom object.

```
/// Demonstrates how to create one or more Account records via the API  

public void CreateAccountSample()
{
    Account account1 = new Account();
    Account account2 = new Account();

    // Set some fields on the account1 object. Name field is not set  

    // so this record should fail as it is a required field.  

    account1.BillingCity = "Wichita";
    account1.BillingCountry = "US";
    account1.BillingState = "KA";
    account1.BillingStreet = "4322 Haystack Boulevard";
    account1.BillingPostalCode = "87901";

    // Set some fields on the account2 object  

    account2.Name = "Golden Straw";
    account2.BillingCity = "Oakland";
    account2.BillingCountry = "US";
    account2.BillingState = "CA";
    account2.BillingStreet = "666 Raiders Boulevard";
    account2.BillingPostalCode = "97502";

    // Create an array of SObjects to hold the accounts  

    sObject[] accounts = new sObject[2];
    // Add the accounts to the SObject array  

    accounts[0] = account1;
    accounts[1] = account2;

    // Invoke the create() call  

    try
    {
        SaveResult[] saveResults = binding.create(accounts);

        // Handle the results  

        for (int i = 0; i < saveResults.Length; i++)
        {
            // Determine whether create() succeeded or had errors  

            if (saveResults[i].success)
            {
                // No errors, so retrieve the Id created for this record  

                Console.WriteLine("An Account was created with Id: {0}",
                    saveResults[i].id);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item {0} had an error updating", i);

                // Handle the errors  

                foreach (Error error in saveResults[i].errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code is: {0}",
                        error.statusCode.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Error message: {0}", error.message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SoapException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}  `
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. You have no methods in those objects and all operations are to be done using their api (web services).

[Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api90/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_samplecode.htm#topic-title) is some sample code in Java and C#

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that the entity classes are there as stubs, but you would have to code a bll layer that would compile these queries, e.g. an update query and then use the entity stub to concatenate it's values to the query?

Comment: what about methods like binding.describeSObject?

Comment: @Jacques: Yes, we have made a layer that compiles these queries for loading and saving an object as well as a collection class that compiles queries for loading objects with a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the classes, like Account, Contact etc are really just data structures that go over the wire. The SforceService (if you're using web reference, not sure what the class is called with WCF), is the entry point for doing things with them, you can for example pass a list of Accounts to the create method to have them created on the salesforce side, there's a number of examples in the [web services API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm).
Query is readonly only, you can't make changes via the query call.